# Tinkercad but offline?

Tags: arduino-uno, software

I have some issues with network and would like to work with arduino everywhere. I use Tinkercad which is great, but I would like to installit to my laptop and work without using WiFi. I couldn't find any "offline tinkercad" but maybe there are any similar programs where you can program AND write code inside.

Comment: I never use such things, but I seem to have an idea that Proteus may be what you want?

Comment: Nah I want arduino, I am  a beginer and Proteus is a bit  complicated

Comment: The only thing you can get that is Arduino is the IDE.

Comment: do you need the hardware sim of tinkercad, or just the ability to run code?

Comment: I want to connect everything to an arduino just like in tinkercad, without using an actual arduino. I do have the Arduino IDE, but there (for what I know) I can only write code, which I can't test without using Arduino

Answer (score 1):

The best replacement (but keep in mind that Tinkercad is prob the best for code AND hardware sim) would be Yenka. They offer a "block style" language but you can go in depth with the hardware more than most programs.

Here is a ref image:
[image]

Comment: is the block style optional, 'cause i want to write code by myself?

Comment: i don't think so sadly